# Como rellenar el color de fondo un label y un checkbox cuando el estado sea "checked"

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un formulario con unos checkbox para cada dia de la semana, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se de click al checkbox, éste se haga de color azul el fondo y las letras blancas.

```css
.label-checkbox{
    margin-right: 0.87rem;
    margin-left: auto;  
    border: 1px solid #4273DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #4273DE;
  }
  .check-day{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<label class="label-checkbox" for="monday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="monday" value="monday"/>
                    Mon
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="tuesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="tuesday" value="tuesday"/>
                    Tues
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="wednesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="wednesday" value="wednesday"/>
                    Wed
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="thursday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="thursday" value="thursday"/>
                    Thu
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="friday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="friday" value="friday"/>
                    Fri
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="saturday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="saturday" value="saturday"/>
                    Sat
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="sunday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="sunday" value="sunday"/>
                    Sun
                </label>
```

Cuando seleccione el dia, quisiera que se viera de la forma de la imagen a continuacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ayudan por favor

Comment: @Barbbadales Hola te dejado una explicación de como se hacían antes y como se debe hacer ahora. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383479/46896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mediante CSS ya no se puede; antes podías hacer esto:

```
.label-checkbox:has(> .check-day:checked) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

y te funcionaba; ahora en 2020 `.has()` se le ha quitado el soporte:

[Documentación #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) [Documentación #2](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)

### Pero si se puede hacer con Javascript y :checked [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) :

```js
$(function () {
    $('input:checked').parent().addClass('add-sign');
    $('input:checked').parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
    $('input:checked').parent().css('color', 'white');
    $(document).on('click',':input',function(){
      var chk = $(this).is(":checked");
      if (chk) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('add-sign');
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
        $(this).parent().css('color', 'white');
      }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass('add-sign');
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).parent().css('color', 'blue');
      }
    });

});
```

```css
.label-checkbox{
    margin-right: 0.87rem;
    margin-left: auto;  
    border: 1px solid #4273DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #4273DE;
  }
.add-sign:before {
  content: '✔';
}
  
  
  .check-day{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label-checkbox" for="monday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="monday" value="monday" checked="checked"/>
                    Mon
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="tuesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="tuesday" value="tuesday"/>
                    Tues
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="wednesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="wednesday" value="wednesday"/>
                    Wed
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="thursday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="thursday" value="thursday"/>
                    Thu
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="friday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="friday" value="friday"/>
                    Fri
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="saturday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="saturday" value="saturday"/>
                    Sat
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="sunday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="sunday" value="sunday"/>
                    Sun
                </label>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Justo lo que necesitaba, pero solo una duda mas, como le podría agregar el logo del cheque?

Comment: @Bardales usas alguna libreria en especial como fontaweson???

Comment: Ocupo mdi - Material Design Icon

Comment: bueno lo simplifique un poco para que no lo ocupes; solo agregando una clase css y un `before`

Comment: como se podria hacer esto mismo pero en vue sin utilizar jQuery?, te dejo el enlace si me puedes ayudar por favor https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/q7usmayh/

Comment: @Bardales esa si te la dejo de tarea: https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-jquery-vue/

Answer (score 1):

Hola buenas tardes esos cambios de color los haría utilizando Javascript.
En el ejemplo que te comparto únicamente tomen como ejemplo el check del día sábado. Intenta dándole clic y comprobando su funcionalidad. Eso mismo lo arias con cada uno de tus botones.

> Código

```js
$("#saturday").click(function(){
    var chk = document.getElementById('saturday');
    if (chk.checked) {
         chk.parentNode.style.color = '#fff';
         chk.parentNode.style.backgroundColor  = '#4273DE';
    } else {
         chk.parentNode.style.color = '#4273DE';
         chk.parentNode.style.backgroundColor  = '#fff';
    }
});
```

```css
.label-checkbox{
    margin-right: 0.87rem;
    margin-left: auto;  
    border: 1px solid #4273DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #4273DE;
  }
  .check-day{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label-checkbox" for="monday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="monday" value="monday"/>
                    Mon
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="tuesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="tuesday" value="tuesday"/>
                    Tues
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="wednesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="wednesday" value="wednesday"/>
                    Wed
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="thursday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="thursday" value="thursday"/>
                    Thu
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="friday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="friday" value="friday"/>
                    Fri
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="saturday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="saturday" value="saturday"/>
                    Sat
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="sunday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="sunday" value="sunday"/>
                    Sun
                </label>
```

Otra forma seria crear una función (isChecked) y después llamarla en cada uno de los checks

> Código

```js
function isChecked(elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
         elem.parentNode.style.color = '#fff';
         elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor  = '#4273DE';
    } else {
         elem.parentNode.style.color = '#4273DE';
         elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor  = '#fff';
    }
}
```

```css
.label-checkbox{
    margin-right: 0.87rem;
    margin-left: auto;  
    border: 1px solid #4273DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #4273DE;
  }
  .check-day{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label-checkbox" for="monday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="monday" value="monday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Mon
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="tuesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="tuesday" value="tuesday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Tues
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="wednesday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="wednesday" value="wednesday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Wed
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="thursday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="thursday" value="thursday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Thu
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="friday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="friday" value="friday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Fri
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="saturday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="saturday" value="saturday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Sat
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="sunday">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check-day" id="sunday" value="sunday" onchange="isChecked(this)"/>
                    Sun
                </label>
```